# Is there any difference on creating Servlet project mannully or via Eclipse Juno?

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I am going to manually create some servlet files. But i checked out some tutorial that mentions Servlet(i.e MyServlet.java) must be created under the folder ../WEB-INF/classes/   .Of course, you need to create web.xml under the  folder WEB-INF to modify the servlet mapping.

But if you are using ECLIPSE JUNO to create a servlet file via Dynamic Project, the servlet will be created in the Java source folder, NOT in the /WEB-INF/classes/.  And it works fine. Thus is there any difference on those two way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Servlet source code can be placed anywhere you want. In maven projects it's `/src/main/java`, as any other class. However after compiling servlet to bytecode it must be placed in `.war` file under `/WEB-INF/classes`. It doesn't matter which tool you use (or maybe you don't use any tool at all), it must produce `.war` file with predefined structure.

That being said you are free to use any environment/IDE/tool and put your servlets source code anywhere you want, as long as you are able to produce standard `.war` file.